# Whence originates the use of the nabla (∇) for a connection or covariant derivative?

Tags: notation, differential-geometry

Who introduced it, when, where, and with what if any rationale?

(Note that I am not asking about the origin of the nabla symbol, which is covered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_symbol).)